# Do topological solitons allow modeling non-degenerate multiple vacua?

Tags: field-theory, vacuum, classical-field-theory, instantons, solitons

I am not well-versed in the research on topological solitons but am interested to make a good sense of its implication.

The highly interesting point in [this new talk by Nick Manton](https://youtu.be/JsAo6QhREkQ?si=0zal_OT1nU5TiEyV&t=213) was where he is noting that multiple vacua can be modeled using solitons.

But are these multiple vacua simply **degenerate** in energy?

Or we can consider **non-degenerate** multiple vacua in different regions of space?